# puppeteer js proxy not recognized

Tags: puppeteer

Following every example I setup a proxy like so:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  'product': 'firefox',
  args: [ '--proxy-server=http://12.239.213.239:8181' ]
 }).then(async browser => {
  try {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 768});
  await page.goto('http://www.whatismyproxy.com/');
```

It goes to the page whatismyproxy.com however the ip address is being recognized as my regular ip.  My expectation was that it would go through the ip provided in the proxy server.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `product:'firefox'` is experimental so you will probably find bugs. See this issue about firefox+proxy: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4093

Comment: Ah got it, thank you! @Matt